# Count number of unique occurrences in multiple files

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have multiple log files where I need to count the number of occurrences of a specific line which has a "unique ID" as a part of it.

So the log line looks like

```
<Some_ID> is related to <Unique_ID>
```

And the above values can be repeated any number of times in the logs,

I need to find a command that counts the unique number of occurrences of the above log line (with different IDs), in multiple files.

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a sample data? And have you tried something so far?

Comment: Does the "Unique_ID" have to be after "is related to", or could it also occur (for counting) in the "Some_ID" field?

Comment: `grep -c Unique_ID *` seems like a simplistic solution; how far does that get you? (Surely there's a duplicate question here somewhere?)

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding guys! I cannot grep with Unique_ID as I wouldn't know all those values. And I need to find the occurrence of "is related to" with many possible Unique_IDs, and these lines can occur multiple times with same Unique_ID, so i want to find the unique occurrences.

Comment: So if there were two lines `345 is related to 123` and `678 is related to 123`, those two lines would count as *one* entry, or *two*?

Comment: "345 is related to 123" and "678 is related to 123", those two lines would count as two entries.

Answer (score 1):

This command will remove all the text prior to the unique ID, then tally the number of occurrences of unique IDs and produce a list of them, sorted in increasing order of occurrence:

```
cat log1 log2 ... logN | sed 's/^.* is related to //' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text between "Some_ID" and "Unique_ID" is truly constant then the following should work (in other words, for example, there's no timestamp):

```
cat log1 log2 ... | grep "Some_ID" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot grep with "Some_ID", as that value can be different for each occurrence, only the text "is related to" between the two values is constant.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your clarifications in the comments, the way I understand your problem is that you are looking for the number of unique relations. So, if given a file as follows:

```
345 is related to 123
678 is related to 123
187 is related to 732
678 is related to 123
```

The result should be 3. To do this, `sort`, `uniq`, `cat`, `wc`, and the pipe operator will be your friend.

If all the files you want to search through are in one folder, you can simply use `*` (a [wildcard operator](https://www.shell-tips.com/2006/11/04/using-bash-wildcards/)) to search every file. For example, `cat *` will print the contents of every file in the current directory. You can also specify multiple files by listing them. `cat file1.txt file2.txt` will print both `file1` and `file2`. This can be combined with the wildcard to specify files in specific subdirectories: `cat dir1/* dir3/*` (skipping `dir2/`). You can also specify a partial filename: `cat file*` will match `file1` and `file123` but not `afile`.

Using the above, you can include *any* files you want into the input for `sort`. The pipe operator (`|`) takes the output of one command and pipes it into the input of another. `cat file1 | sort` will sort the contents of `file1`. You can then pipe this into `uniq` to filter out all the duplicate entries, and then count the lines with `wc` like so: `cat file1 | sort | uniq | wc -l`.

Using the example file I gave above the `sort` command will change the output into:

```
187 is related to 732
345 is related to 123
678 is related to 123
678 is related to 123
```

`uniq` will remove the duplicate entries (in this example at the bottom):

```
187 is related to 732
345 is related to 123
678 is related to 123
```

and `wc -l` will count the lines and return `3`.

***NOTE:*** This will count `123 is related to 321` *and* `321 is related to 123` *as **two** separate relations. If you want to get around this you will need to do something more complicated involving parsing the input data and organizing the entries into a table or hashmap.*

*Also, on extremely large inputs this command chain will likely hang and look as if it has frozen. If you are using large sets of input data I would look  into setting up a database to manage the data, as that will allow you to use queries to perform this type of search much faster.*

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for explaining. I will try the above and get back to you :)

Comment: @Tania Did this work for you? If it did, please accept the answer so others can easily find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the IDs, we can do this with `sed` and poke them into a while loop to `grep` and `wc`.

```
cat files | sed -e 's/.*is related to //g' \
| while IFS= read -r ID; do
    count=`grep $ID files | wc -l`
    echo "$ID = $count"
done
```